# Regular expression to replace improper query

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am writing a small tool in Java to read sql queries and process them but in some of my queries 
single quotes(') is embeded inside a another single quotes sentences because of this I can't able to process the query plz see the below example for more details so I am trying to find a regular expression to pre-process the query

example:

Original Query

```
insert into person values ('kumar's kandan', 23, 'Male')
```

pre-processed Query

```
insert into person values ('kumar''s kandan', 23, 'Male')
```

Comment: This seems like a hack to the original solution: escape out the value before constructing the query. Which begs the question: Why aren't you going after the original problem? More to the point, you're best bet is fix the original issue, you're never going to have a 100% working solution finding and correcting stray quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A PreparedStatement or something similar should be used to escape these characters when producing the SQL.   This tool sounds like it should just be assuming the query is already correct rather than trying to fix issues on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all single quotes that have a word character in front and behind:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\w)'(?=\\w)","''");
```

although this of course does not guarantee that everything will be escaped correctly.